# Windows IoT on Pi B3: SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'

Tags: asp.net-core, sqlite, raspberry-pi, windowsiot

after I installing a asp.net core 2.0 Application to my raspberry pi B3 I got the following error message from windows PowerShell:

```
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
  Connection id "0HLD7KSSQUCOB", Request id "0HLD7KSSQUCOB:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()
```

in code I open Data.db with:

```
public partial class DatabaseEntities : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseEntities() : base()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder xOptionsBuilder)
    {
        xOptionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=Data\\Data.db");
    }
}
```

And in the Razor-Pages I refer to the DataBase with this object:

```
public static DatabaseEntities DataBase = new DatabaseEntities();
```

I don't know how I can handle this problem,
thankful for any response.
Martin.

Comment: I guess there is no `Data` directory in the place where it looks.

Comment: I shame my self. Your totally right. **dotnet publish . -r win8-arm** destroy logical the original structure off my project. I don't focus this behavioral. Thank you a lot.